# How to connect a remote MS SQL Server in neo4j tool?

Tags: sql-server, database, neo4j

I'm unable to add or connect MS SQL server remote Database in Neo4j?
I've tried several times by adding the remote server URL in the Neo4j tool

Also, how do we make this tool available to everyone or end users without installing on their devices?

Can anyone please guide me?

Please treat this as a request.

https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-connect-a-remote-sql-server-in-neo4j-tool/37962?u=kdplghna

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the community post, Neo4j Desktop is not a general db management app, it is specifically for managing and working with Neo4j, so MS SQL support will not be added. Please search for other tools that are designed to work with that db.

If you want to connect to an MS SQL server from Neo4j, then you could use APOC to perform a load via JDBC:

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/database-integration/load-jdbc/